# Pick and Crop Image in Android issue in android Nougat 7.0

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-7.0-nougat

I have use compile `com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.3.+` lib to pick and crop, I have problem to Android Nougat when opening camera app close error display. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Logcat Error:

> Java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity { java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.net.Uri android.content.Intent.getData()' on a null object reference

open Dialog below.

[image]

Comment: `camera app close error display` share logcat . Use latest `android-image-cropper:2.4.+`

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.toString()' on a null object reference

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. That would include the entire Java stack trace, along with your code that is triggering the crash.

Comment: hi@santosh backar

Comment: add some code @SantoshBachkar

Answer (score 1):

use this lib 
compile 'com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:1.0.1@aar'

I also faced the same problem in Nougat 7.0 
Now its working properly

Answer (score 1):

The error clearly shows, that when your app launches the pick and crop. It goes into activity result, there the result or intent is found null. Hence the app crashes.

But you need to look at your code routine. As it should not invoke onActivityResult before the whole process is completed.